# How to load ClojureScript output from a page with multi-level path?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I'm developing a single-page webapp using Boot.  It originally started from the [Holy Grail example](https://github.com/danielsz/holygrail).

My Compojure routes are defined like this:

```
(defroutes routes
  ; sente
  (GET  "/chsk"  req ((:ring-ajax-get-or-ws-handshake (:sente system)) req))
  (POST "/chsk"  req ((:ring-ajax-post (:sente system)) req))
  ; everything else
  (GET "/*" [] (-> (resource-response "/index.html")
                   (content-type "text/html")))
  ; vestige of old times
  (route/not-found "Not Found"))
```

Note the star in the `"/*"` route: I want all requests to return `index.html`, with the ClojureScript part handling the actual routes.

I'm running the application in the dev mode, here's a snippet from `build.boot`:

```
(deftask dev
  "Run a restartable system in the Repl"
  []
  (comp
   (environ :env {:http-port "3000"})
   (watch :verbose true)
   (system :sys #'dev-system :auto true :files ["handler.clj"])
   (reload :on-jsload 'myapp.core/init!)
   (cljs :source-map true)
   (repl :server true :init-ns 'myapp.user)))
```

It works well for single-level paths, like `localhost:3000/test`.  It breaks, though, for the pages with mult-level paths, e.g. `localhost:3000/foo/bar`.

The part of `index.html` that loads JavaScript looks like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Originally it was `src="main.js"`, but I've added the leading slash so it finds `main.js` from a multi-level page.  Without the slash, the browser probably looks for the file in the directory `[somewhere-in-cljs-output]/foo/main.js`, assuming the page `localhost:3000/foo/bar`.

Now, `main.js` is generated by ClojureScript compiler, and here it is:

```
var CLOSURE_UNCOMPILED_DEFINES = null;
if(typeof goog == "undefined") document.write('<script src="main.out/goog/base.js"></script>');
document.write('<script src="main.out/cljs_deps.js"></script>');
document.write('<script>if (typeof goog != "undefined") { goog.require("boot.cljs.main26293"); } else { console.warn("ClojureScript could not load :main, did you forget to specify :asset-path?"); };</script>');
```

When it runs on a page `localhost:3000/foo/bar`, I see the warning.

Apparently the problem's the same as with the original `main.js` reference, in that the paths of required JavaScript files are relative, not absolute.  How do I get them to be absolute?

I think I have to change the `cljs` task invocation in `build.boot`, but not sure how, because my mental model of how Boot works is very spotty.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little tinkering led to the following change in the `dev` task of `build.boot`:

```
   (cljs :source-map true
         :compiler-options {:asset-path "/main.out"})
```

Comment: consider marking your answer as the correct answer :)

Comment: Yeah, at the time the stupid SO's interface didn't allow me to.